# IOS, Swift: How come my subclass of UIScrollView doesn't scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to subclass UIScrollView, to do some custom drawing and creation of customized UIViews. The drawing and creation of UIViews works fine, but the view just doesn't scroll.

The internal height of the view is fixed, and I calculate it in the init method. I also override the intrinsticContentSize method, but that doesn't work.

What am I doind wrong?

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIScrollView, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    // MARK: - layout constants
    private var _intrinsicSize: CGSize?;

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame);
        self.didLoad();
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
        self.didLoad();
    }

    private func didLoad() {
        self.delegate = self;
        var result = CGSize();
        result.height = CGFloat(_halfHourHeight * 48);
        result.width = 500;
        _intrinsicSize = result;
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return self._intrinsicSize!;
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect);

        // some custom drawing here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll views generally don't have an intrinsic size, it usually doesn't mean anything. They have a frame, bounds and content size - it's the content size you're interested in setting and it goes into setting the bounds.

The content size is the total size of all the subviews, and the bounds is the window onto the currently visible area of those subviews.

You also wouldn't usually have custom drawing code, though you can. You'd usually add subviews to do that drawing for the scroll view.

Comment: ContentSize! Thank you! I knew it was something simple that I was missing here...